# jQuery remove appended text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a like function, where on default state it is on black color, and whenever the user clicks the like button it turns blue and a "Liked" text will appear besides the like icon

It is working, clicking liked will turn to blue, then clicking the like again will turn to black. The problem arises when i use the append function, when i liked it, "LikedLiked" is showing, it supposed to be 1 'Liked" only and whenever i clicked again the like button, it removes all the element including the like icon. What i want is, just to remove the text only.

here's my code

```
<div class="extra content">
  <a class="likeicon">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
  </a>
```

my jQuery

```
$(".likeicon").click(function(){
if($(this).css("color") === "rgb(0, 0, 255)"){
  $(this).css("color", "black");
  $(this).empty();
} else {
  $(this).css("color", "blue");
  $(this).append("Liked")
}  
});
```

i've checked here on stackoverflow, i tried using .empty() and .remove() . but all of them get rids of my text and my like icon/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this, with `css`:

```js
$(".likeicon").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

```css
.likeicon.active i{
  color: blue;
}
.likeicon{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.likeicon span{
  display: none;
  color: blue;
}
.likeicon.active span{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="extra content">
  <a class="likeicon">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Liked</span>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add text in elemrnt with id

```
 $(this).append('<span id="liked_txt">Liked</span>');
```

and when you want to remove it use

```
$("#liked_txt").remove();
```

Comment: it doesn't get rid of the text. the "liked" is still there

Comment: ohh i get it, the code should be like this `$("#liked_txt").remove();` with the pound sign symbol.. thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some extra CSS. Try using the :after pseudo-element:

```
.likeicon {
    color: black;
}

.like:after {
    content: "liked";
    color: blue;
}
```

Then just use jQuery to add and remove the 'like' class to the anchor tag, within the click handler.

```
$('.likeicon').click(function(e) {
    e.defaultPrevented;
    if ($(this).hasClass('like')) {
        $(this).removeClass('like');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('like');
    }
});
```